# TensorFlow2 keeps installing the same version

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to run a program in my Raspberry but i can't because it needs at least TensorFlow 2.2.0, while I have TensorFlow 2.0.0 . I tried several times to install TensorFlow 2.2.0 and 2.3.0 . But after install it, it always comes that is 2.0.0 still.

[Versions of TensorFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egow7.png)

Somebody can tell me what happens? Thank you!!

Comment: Could you check if you don't have more than one python version installed using the command `py -0` provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312590/how-can-i-check-all-the-installed-python-versions-on-windows

Comment: @PrateekBhatt I can't run that command on the RPI, if I run python -V I get 2.7.16 and if I run python3 -V I get 3.7.3

Comment: Could you try first uninstalling the tensorflow==2.0.0 and then check if no other version is installed and later install tensorflow==2.2.0. You might have tried it I just want to know the outcome of it.

Comment: @PrateekBhatt what I notice is that when I pip3 uninstall tensorflow, it uninstalls the 2.2.0 version but I still can import tensorflow, so the TF that is using when I run a program isnt that, the dependencies that my RPI are using are in another place

Comment: exactly, maybe try pip uninstall tensorflow once and see what comes back? just curious.

Comment: @PrateekBhatt Does this make any sense ? https://imgur.com/QbH9l5u

Comment: could you go to the mentioned location in the site-packages and delete the package itself? Also try once with pip3 uninstall tensorflow==2.0.0

Comment: @PrateekBhatt thank u mate!!!! This worked for me https://imgur.com/a/5d3wgiq

Comment: Nice to know. I will just add it as an answer so that it will help others out with an official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the package in the `/python3.x/site-packages` and remove the `tensorflow` directory using `rm`.

Then install the needed `tensorflow` version following the installation instruction found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#raspberry-pi) in the official documentation of `tensorflow`.

Also attaching the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma7s0.jpg) from the comment of @pablo Gracia S.