# List down all python virtual environment created

Tags: python

I need to check if there is any virtual environment is present or not in the path C:\Program Files\Python3,  but I want to perform this with the help of command prompt in windows and not through anaconda prompt or jupyter notebook. There were some packages installed in virtual Environment but I might not aware of, so for this reason I need to list down all the virtual environment created in the past days. I just need a way to check, or some code to type in cmd which will help me to list down. If there is any way then please help.

Comment: So you are talking of Anaconda environnements ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53312590/8878627

Comment: @BrookeJackson yes Conda environment, sorry for the confusion, actually im not familiar with python environment related things

Comment: is this what you need(?) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767329/11747148

Answer (score 0):

you can enter in your `cmd` the command `set Path`

you can see all your paths including the python ones

you can also look at `py -0` to see all your version of python that installed

```
    >py -0
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.10-64 *
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, there is a file typicaly located at : `C:\Users\Bill\.conda\environments.txt` with the list of all environnements

Comment: I searched but didnt get any folder named Bill, and  inside Users, there were only 2 folder(Administrator & Public) that means there were no environment  created?

Comment: Not at all, the folder located here change from computer to computer, try to look in the Administrator or Public folder to find a .conda folder

Comment: Bill here basically stands for the windows user you're using in your system. The one you start your system with

Answer (score 0):

If using anaconda prompt, you can simply execute:

```
conda info --env
```

and it will list down all the environments. However, you can navigate to the directory of conda environments using this path in windows:

```
/Users/Username/.conda/envs
```

and it should lead you to it.

Comment: thanks @Prats, but im not using anaconda prompt, I am on windows command prompt.

Comment: I've mentioned the path for that as well..