# how can I fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm' after installation 'tqdm'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have installed `tqdm` using `pip install tqdm`

but I still got an error that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'`,
how can I fix this?

my code looks like this `from tqdm import tqdm`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options I can advise:

1. Check that you have `tdqm` with pip show `tdqm`
2. Check that you're using the correct virtual environment.
3. You can try uninstall and then reinstall it again.

Comment: I checked the `tdqm`, which is on my package list.
I am using `Python 3.10.1`.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalled it, still not working.
How can I check if I am using the correct virtual environment?

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer actually. You can try to check whether you're using the correct environment. Or just try to reinstall package and might be this will help

Comment: You can use `which python` command to see the python executable you're using

Comment: The `tdqm` package is installed in `Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, but I am using a virtual environment and the location is `.\bin\python`. how can I install `tdqm` package in my virtual environment? thank you

Comment: I tried `which python`, it shows I am using `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use a virtual environment, ensure the correct environment is activated.
2. Also, you might need to use pip3 instead of pip, as in `pip3 install tqdm`.
3. Finally, check if you have multiple versions of python installed. For [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312590/how-can-i-check-all-the-installed-python-versions-on-windows)/[Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117945/too-many-different-python-versions-on-my-system-and-causing-problems)/[Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547554/multiple-python-versions-on-the-same-machine). If you have multiple versions of python. Delete unused versions.